# Constant Refreshing php page on NGINX + PHP-FPM causes memory to spike, how can I tell nginx or php-fpm to ignore cancelled web requests

Tags: php, nginx

I am running magento2 on an nginx server that uses php-fpm. On refreshing the webpage multiple times on each reload being within milliseconds the memory increases until the system runs out of memory. A single user could go to the website and refresh the page multiple times and crash the website how can I prevent this from happening. What modifications can I make to NGINX or PHP-FPM to prevent this from happening.

Current PHP-FPM Configuraton:

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 50
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 35
```